# Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, php, json, linechart

Good day, I'm having trouble making a google line  chart.
My target chart is like this: (see picture)
[image]

but what i have made is this: (see picture)
[image]

here's my javascript code:

```
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['line', 'corechart', 'bar','controls', 'table']});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartMonthly);

 function drawChartMonthly() {
var jsonData = $.ajax({
     url: "analytics/platform-sales.php",
     dataType: "json",
     async: false
   }).responseText;

   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

       var options = {
         title: 'Music Services sales',
         pointSize: 5
       };

       var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div_platform'));
       chart.draw(data, options);

   }
```

here's my html:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <div id="chart_div_platform" style='width: 1200px; height: 600px;'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's my sample json data:

```
    {"cols":[{"label":"Month","type":"date"},{"label":"Platform","type":"string"},{"label":"Amount","type":"number"}],
"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,3,1)"},{"v":"Tunecore"},{"v":19932}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,4,1)"},{"v":"Platform1"},{"v":17930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,4,1)"},{"v":"Platform2"},{"v":16930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,4,1)"},{"v":"Platform3"},{"v":15930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,4,1)"},{"v":"Platform4"},{"v":14930}]},

{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,5,1)"},{"v":"Platform1"},{"v":17930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,5,1)"},{"v":"Platform2"},{"v":16930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,5,1)"},{"v":"Platform3"},{"v":15930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,5,1)"},{"v":"Platform4"},{"v":14930}]},

{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,6,1)"},{"v":"Platform1"},{"v":17930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,6,1)"},{"v":"Platform2"},{"v":16930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,6,1)"},{"v":"Platform3"},{"v":15930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,6,1)"},{"v":"Platform4"},{"v":14930}]},

{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,7,1)"},{"v":"Platform1"},{"v":17930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,7,1)"},{"v":"Platform2"},{"v":16930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,7,1)"},{"v":"Platform3"},{"v":15930}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,7,1)"},{"v":"Platform4"},{"v":14930}]}]}
```

Can you guys give me an example. please. Thank you.

Comment: Please check this properly https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: yes i've checked it already but i can't find an example like on the first picture with the strings are on the left side, dates on bottom and sales(numbers) on plot.

Comment: Please chekc https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples and https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable